# Extract test python-selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, extract

How can I extract numeric digits in Element HTLMthe text to copy it (CTRL + C) which changes every time, when the script is closed and reopened?

`<span class="inSubject subject"> <a href=" www. example.com" title="" class="viewLink title-subject" data-example-id="92fjjkkla6a07ea9601d770b816f79b927c8a"> 5023ABCDEFSGILMOPW</a> </span>` `

In this example the number to extract is:  "5023"

Comment: Can you give me some code? You probably can find the element and use .text to get the text and regex to get only the numbers.

Comment: span class="int subject-title"> <a href="www.example" title="" class="viewLink " data-id="d31b610020ea603d2f9d6jfjhdfc293f11bdc2">2061ABKHDOPHELLO</a> </span>..

Change ever cycle

Comment: Use XPath or another selector to get the element and then use .text to get the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
import pyperclip

strrr = '5023ABCDEFSGILMOPW'

value = re.search('^\d+', strrr)[0]

pyperclip.copy(value)
```

for pyperclip working, it should be installed with pip:

```
pip install pyperclip
```

or get more code description, where we can extract more info to help out

Comment: mmm... unfortunately the string is variable, it changes with each script cycle.

Comment: with the right focus on the entire body of the xpath and with element.text, finally the entire text appears to me  example"2061ABKHDOPHELLO". Now it remains to understand, how to extract only the numeric part  example "2061" and insert it into a variable. You've been very helpful for now. a small step is still missing, we hope to succeed

Comment: now it works perfectly. with this extra command: 

strrr=element.text

value = re.search('^\d+', strrr)[0]

pyperclip.copy(value)

super thanks!!